# Retrieve value from Snowflake JSON column

Tags: sql, json, sqlite, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

i have a json column with each record as

[
   {
     "DATE": 20190910
     "NAME": "Tom"
   },
   {
     "DATE": 20190504
     "NAME": "Bob"
    }
]

The above is one record in the column.

I need to retrieve the record as Tom,Bob in a single record in the column.

Please refer the attached image for clarity.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTBwF.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

so expanding the input data to multiple rows of input json, to show how to group it on values carried in the flatten pattern

```
with rows_of_json as (
    select parse_json(raw_json_string) as json 
    from values 
        ('[ { "DATE": 20190910, "NAME": "Tom1" }, { "DATE": 20190504, "NAME": "Bob1" } ]'),
        ('[ { "DATE": 20190910, "NAME": "Tom2" }, { "DATE": 20190504, "NAME": "Bob2" } ]')
        d(raw_json_string)
)
select array_agg(f.value:NAME::text) within group (order by f.value:DATE::number) as ordered_list  
from rows_of_json j, lateral flatten (input=>j.json) f
group by f.seq;
```

gives:

```
ORDERED_LIST
[    "Bob2",    "Tom2"  ]
[    "Bob1",    "Tom1"  ]
```

This is flattening the data, and using the seq inside the flatten to re-group the data on based on the rows that came from..

Also sorting the data based on a property in the object, if your wanting the original order, then in the above context:

```
array_agg(f.value:NAME::text) within group (order by f.index) as ordered_list
```

gives:

```
ORDERED_LIST
[    "Tom2",    "Bob2"  ]
[    "Tom1",    "Bob1"  ]
```